# How to create sharing icons with the share count number showing?

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-media, google-plus

See a sample article on [theonion.com](http://www.theonion.com/articles/list-of-politically-achievable-reforms-down-to-jus,30977/)

[image]

I know how to create icons for these sites without using their standard widget, but how did they get the number of share, bellow each icon ? Is there an API to ask for it ?

Comment: Yes is the simple answer. Search the individual APIs for further details.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? RTFM is a valid answer now ?

Comment: I can't find any information on how to do this for twitter, for instance.

Comment: Did you even search? Took me a minute to [find](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

Comment: Actually, I need to call count.json, as answered on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Twitter**

use the URL :

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com
```

It will return a JSON string :

```
{"count":8026,"url":"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/"}
```

**Facebook**

The URL is

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com
```

But see [stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)

**Google +**

The URL is

```
https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

More social sites at https://gist.github.com/2640302